# SQL Server Repeatedly runs a query not in a loop

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm currently learning how to create stored procedures in a SQL Server environment.

I have a query block that I am using that follows along with the Joes2Pros SQL server series.

The T-SQL syntax currently looks like this:

```
Use JProCo
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetProductListByCategory @Category VarChar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ProductID, ProductName, RetailPrice
    FROM dbo.CurrentProducts
    WHERE Category = @Category
END

EXECUTE sp_GetProductListByCategory 'No-Stay'
```

Running this code gets me a result that looks like this:

```
(80 row(s) affected)

(80 row(s) affected)

(80 row(s) affected)

(80 row(s) affected)

(80 row(s) affected)

(80 row(s) affected)

(80 row(s) affected)

(80 row(s) affected)

(80 row(s) affected)

(80 row(s) affected)

(80 row(s) affected)

(80 row(s) affected)
```

What I was expecting was a table full of results and records. Instead, it looks like the query ran quite a few times. What I'd like to know is:

Why does this appear to be running many times? I don't see anything that would create a loop in this logic set. (I tried the above T-SQL code without the BEGIN and END statements and the same behavior exists)

Answer (score 2):

You have included the call to the SP in the SP itself. Create the SP in a batch of its own.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetProductListByCategory @Category VarChar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ProductID, ProductName, RetailPrice
    FROM dbo.CurrentProducts
    WHERE Category = @Category
END
```

And then call it.

```
EXECUTE sp_GetProductListByCategory 'No-Stay'
```

Comment: You can separate batches with the keyword "Go" - put that in between the two pieces of code, to tell SQL that it shouldn't be run together.